# How to upload Django Project in Digitalocean?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, digital-ocean

I am uploading Django project in Digitalocean server. I have uploaded all my files in Digitalocean and I am using MongoDb database.

But when I run my project it showing below error:

```
 raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017:
  [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description:
  <TopologyDescription id: 5f6c644e91288a299c34f17e, topology_type:
  Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017)
  server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=
  AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>
```

This error is Related Mongodb database or Something else? I don't know how to upload Mongodb database in Digitalocean.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using external MongoDB in cloud instead manage your own, like this

https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas

It contains a free plan as well, and if it is a small project with a small amount of data it can be good.

But if you still don't want use external, you need install MongoDB server on the same digital ocean server, and only after it you will be able connect use localhost